# Find the rate of change of the temperature at a point

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

> The temperature at a point (x,y,z) is given by
> $$T(x,y,z)=1000e^{−x^2−2y^2−z^2}$$ where T is measured in $^{∘}C$ and
> x, y, and z in meters.
>
> Find the rate of change of the temperature at the point P(2,−2,2) in
> the direction toward the point Q(3,−4,3).

This is what I did:

1. Gradient $$\nabla T=(-2x\hat{i}-4y\hat{j}-2z\hat{k})$$
2. Unit vector: $$\hat{u}=\frac{u}{|u|}=\frac{\hat{i}-6\hat{j}+\hat{k}}{\sqrt{38}}$$
3. Dot-product of gradient and unit vector: $$D_uf(x,y,z)=\big[-2x\hat{i}-4y\hat{j}-2z\hat{k}\big]\bigg[\frac{1}{\sqrt{38}}\hat{i}-\frac{6}{\sqrt{38}}\hat{j}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{38}}\hat{k}\bigg]$$
4. Insert for Point coordinates for the variables: $$D_uf(2,-2,2)=\big[-4\hat{i}+4\hat{j}-4\hat{k}\big]\bigg[\frac{1}{\sqrt{38}}\hat{i}-\frac{6}{\sqrt{38}}\hat{j}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{38}}\hat{k}\bigg]$$
   $$D_uf(2,-2,2)=\bigg[-\frac{4}{\sqrt{38}}-\frac{48}{\sqrt{38}}-\frac{4}{\sqrt{38}}\bigg]$$

which gives:

$$D_uf(2,-2,2)=-\frac{56}{\sqrt{38}}$$

but this is completely wrong. Any ideas what happened?

Thanks

Comment: Where did the exponential function disappear in the derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient is $\nabla T = (-2x,-4y,-2z)T$

and

$u = (1,-2,1)$

$\hat u = (\frac 1{\sqrt 6}, -\frac 2{\sqrt 6},\frac 1{\sqrt 6})$

Then when you plug in the variables at $(2,-2,2)$ there is an error.

$(-4,8,-4)\cdot (1,-2,1)\frac {1000 e^{-16}}{\sqrt6}$

$-4000\sqrt 6\ e^{-16}$

Comment: Thanks...:....!